# display time counter in terms of second and minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a time counter that works for 120 seconds (i.e 2 minutes. Although it is working fine, but i want that it should get displayed in terms of minutes and second. here is the code at [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/dk2or4qs/3/)

```
<span id="count">2:00</span> 
<button type="submit" id="startClock" form="form1"value="Submit">Submit</button>

$('#startClock').click(function(){
    var counter = 120;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

I want that the result should get displayed like this

```
02:00
```

and the timer should go on decreasing

Comment: You divide with `/` operator )

Comment: Here's a countdown timer i made once,http://jsfiddle.net/rstsu5zs/ based on http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/. feel free to use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code to convert your seconds to `m:s` format:

```
var str = parseInt(counter / 60) + ':' + (counter % 60);
```

full code:

```
$('#startClock').click(function() {
    var counter = 120;
    setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        var str = parseInt(counter / 60) + ':' + (counter % 60);
        if (counter >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = str;
        }
        if (counter === 0) {
            alert('sorry, out of time');
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }, 1000);

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/dk2or4qs/3/)

Comment: it didn't worked on my fiddle and i wasn't able to see the modified code in ur js fiddle, could u plz recheck ur fiddle once

Answer (score 2):

You can use Date Object:

```
var d = new Date(counter * 1000);  
span.innerHTML = d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also work

```
var min = parseInt(counter/60);
var sec = Math.abs(counter - (min*60));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk2or4qs/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this functions:

```
var 
 millisecToTimeStruct = function (ms) {
        var d, h, m, s;
        if (isNaN(ms)) {
            return {};
        }
        d = ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        h = (d - ~~d) * 24;
        m = (h - ~~h) * 60;
        s = (m - ~~m) * 60;
        return {
            d: ~~d,
            h: ~~h,
            m: ~~m,
            s: ~~s
        };
    },
    toFormattedStr = function (tStruct) {
        var res = '';
        if (typeof tStruct === 'object') {
            res += tStruct.m + ':' + tStruct.s;
        }
        return res;
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dk2or4qs/5/

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

html:

```
<span id="count">02:00</span>
<button type="submit" id="startClock" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

js:

```
$('#startClock').click(function () {
    var counter = 120;
    setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            var time =new Date(counter*1000);
            var m = time.getMinutes();
            m = m<10?'0'+m:m;
            var s = time.getSeconds();
            span.innerHTML = m+':'+s;
        }
        if (counter === 0) {
            alert('sorry, out of time');
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dk2or4qs/6/)

this will change the timer with the format "02:00".

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
 span.innerHTML = counter;
```

by :

```
var m = Math.floor(counter/60);
var s = counter-(m*60);
if(s<10){s="0"+s;}
span.innerHTML =m+":"+s;
```

and it would work for any number of time down to `0:01`

Here's you fiddle forked and tuned: http://jsfiddle.net/6LL7ofyp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try (format `mm:ss`):

```js
var span = document.querySelector("#count");

function countDown(counter){

 var interval = setInterval(function(){
  
  var minutes = ((counter / 60) | 0) + "";
  var seconds = (counter % 60) + "";
  var format = ""
                      + new Array(3-minutes.length).join("0") + minutes 
                      + ':' 
                      + new Array(3-seconds.length).join("0") + seconds;

  span.innerHTML = format;

  counter--;

  if(counter === 0){
   clearInterval(interval);
   alert('sorry, out of time')
  }
        
 },1e3)
}

countDown(120);
```

```html
<span id="count"><span>
```